# Use laravel to create a REST-API?

Tags: api, rest

In order to create a REST API my supervisor suggested the php-framework Laravel to me.

Besides authentification, pagination and other requirements I should implement the [Feed Item Query Language](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-atompub-fiql-00) to filter requests over the `URL` query string.

I'm completly new to Laravel so I searched the internet for a matching package or a built in function (e.g. for pagination there is something very simple to use). But I can't find anything in this direction... the only thing that comes close to the topic is this [package](https://github.com/esbenp/bruno). Unfortunately it doesn't provide support for the latest laravel version's.

Maybe someone has a clue if I missed something? Has someone experience with Laravel and can recommend something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have been working on Laravel for my finals project and I've learned quite a bit in the process, so I'll try to answer.

As I understand, you need something to filter results from database or from request object. Well Laravel is great in that as it has built functions for such a thing. It is using eloquent models to access database. If you don't know about it yet read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators).

Look at [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) in laravel documentation and check available methods for filtering.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Kovalski, I'll have a look.